# Java: Creating a window for a text based RPG

Tags: java, dialog, window

> So I'm working on a text based RPG as part of my programming class and
>   I would like my friends to be able to play it without a compiler. Is
>   there anyway I can put the game in a Dialog box or window so they can
>   just run it if they have Java?
>
> *Edit: Code Can be provided but I don't think you'll need it as it is just the game fit for running in a compiler.

I think I'm confusing myself and everyone else. I am running the game in my IDE, jGrasp (because that's what we're supposed to use) and in there it will run. Unless I can export it as something else/make it appear as another file I don't know how to let people who don't have jGrasp or Eclipse play it.

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: ...running in a compiler? This isn't [the IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/1994/westley.hint).

Comment: Yeah the point is that I want to run it outside of the compiler so that my friends could play it/test it for me. I'm not sure if that's accomplished through the use of dialogue boxes or what.

Comment: Ever heard of a file extension called `JAR`..?

Comment: Probably not. Ok, in my IDE when I run the program it runs. That's the only way I can get it to run; unless I can export it as something else I don't know of a way to let people who don't have an IDE like jGrasp or Eclipse run the game.

Comment: It makes NO differnce what type of game you have in mind, or enen that it is a game in the first place. Do not use tags on this site if you are not willing to read what each one means here. This is a site for programmers, and to us, RPG is a programming language not some irrelevant trivia about your game.

Comment: Sorry about that, new to Stack, didn't even know they had descriptions for each tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a little bit tricky if you are just starting out with Java, but I will walk you through it.

You will need to first turn your code into a JAR file. Depending on what IDE you are using, this can usually be found in file/export. Then you will need to run the file through a command prompt, such as Terminal.

Locate the jar file you exported, and put it into a easy to find location.

Open terminal and type this into the command prompt: `java -jar /Path/to/yourfile.jar`

Thats it! It is as if you are running it from your compiler. Just give your friends these instructions, and they will be able to play your game. Enjoy!

If you need something easier to run, look into Swing gui. This will be easier for your friends, but much harder for you.